# How to get the current MavenSession or MavenExecutionRequest from a Plexus Component

Tags: maven, maven-2, components, mojo, plexus

I created a Plexus component to house common logic for several Mojos I want to create. I have been able to pass information like `localRepository` and project from the Mojo (and test cases).

I was wondering if there is a way to get the `MavenSession` or `MavenExecutionRequest` from within the component without having to pass them as parameters from a Mojo. I know my component will be running from a Maven Mojo.

I'm using Maven 2 in this instance.

Comment: I know the question is quite old. Thomas, do you want to "reuse" the identical session across several phases or do you just need a reference to the current MavenSession of the phase?

Comment: Hmm.. if there was, I guess it would not be thread safe any more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is, nor would I think it's a good idea.

From my understanding, what you're aiming to achieve is have a commons-like component, that will be used for several mojos.  This requires the current Maven session to be passed in & used to subsequently pass back a value.

The way Maven works however, is that it runs goals from plugins in an almost container-like environment.  Each plugin is allowed to act within a particular [Maven Phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), as defined by the `<executions />`.  This allows Maven to separate the complexities of building, testing, checking, deploying etc. etc.  Calling `mvn clean install`, unless I'm mistake, is two separate executions, one to run the `clean` [build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), followed by the `install`.

It is therefore not safe to assume that the `MavenSession` and subsequent `MavenExecutionRequest` represent the same instance used in a previous call.  `clean` is a separate call, whose logic shouldn't be maintained in a new session.

So, what I'm essentially saying, is that whilst having a common plexus component is a good practice, particularly to maintain consistency across your mojos, it is right practice (almost [ioc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)), to provide the appropriate session each time.

I hope that's the answer you're looking for.  Rather long, but to understand why you need to provide the session, think `Maven`.